# How do I avoid writing CSV header multiple times

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I am writing a csv file from a multiple dictionaries with loop.
Where I am using key as a header and dictionaries values as entries.

Saving a csv is perfectly working but header is added each time when new dictionary entries are added to csv.

Is there a way to avoid writing headers multiple times so that I could save csv with a single header and multiple entries from dictionaries.
This is how I am directly saving csv fom multiple dictionaries:

```
with open('./raw_data.csv', 'a', newline='') as f_output:
writer = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=header)
writer.writeheader()
  for elem in trainingLogs:
      writer.writerow(elem)
```

Where trainLogs is a list which includes nested dictionaries.

Hoping for some help.

THank you

Comment: Is this something where lines will accrue over time, so it has to survive multiple executions of the script?

Comment: Hi, regarding lines yes. Data are extracted based on dates. But I am not able to stop re writing headers..... .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
csv_file = 'raw_data.csv'
if not os.path.exists(csv_file ):
    f_output = open(csv_file ,'w')
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=header)
    writer.writeheader()
else:
    f_output = open(csv_file ,'a')
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=header)

for elem in trainingLogs:
     writer.writerow(elem)
f_output.close()
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. May be you missed something in first line..... :: if not os.path.exists....